# Android AOSP Contacts app and Calls.VOICEMAIL_TYPE

Tags: android

Im trying to build the Contacts app from AOSP as a Android project in Eclipse. I can't find the reference

Calls.VOICEMAIL_TYPE

in code CallLogFragmentTest.java

```
private void insertVoicemail(String number, long date, int duration) {
    Object[] values = getValuesToInsert(number, date, duration, Calls.VOICEMAIL_TYPE);
    // Must have the same index as the row.
    values[CallLogQuery.VOICEMAIL_URI] =
            ContentUris.withAppendedId(VoicemailContract.Voicemails.CONTENT_URI, mIndex);
    insertValues(values);
}
```

Even in my other Android environment the variable VOICEMAIL_TYPE does not exist?

Has someone done this, if so exactly what libs did you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VOICEMAIL_TYPE` is found in `CallLog.Calls`, as you can see from [the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/provider/CallLog.java).

Here are two reasons I can think of for why you are missing this:

- You do not have all the right source code (i.e., your copy of `CallLog` does not have `VOICEMAIL_TYPE`)
- You actually set up an Android project (with an `android.jar` as part of your build path), as `VOICEMAIL_TYPE` is marked as `@hide`, so while it is part of an OS build, it is not part of the Android SDK

There may be other reasons as well.

Comment: Thanks! You pointed me in the right direction, it must be my android.jar I will need to use the internal android.jar any idea where this is located from the compiled AOSP?

Comment: @powder366: I am not aware that there is an "internal android.jar". You get `CallLog` by having access to `CallLog`'s compiled classes in your classpath. See the various instructions for editing your classpath in http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html

Comment: You might be right. This is a good read: https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

CommonsWare pointed me out in the right direction and I solved it by building the AOSP and then I got out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar and added it first in my build path in Eclipse